# Postback always returns status code 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, http, redirect, iis-express

Any sort of postback, Ajax or standard MVC form submit, is returning Status code 301. It seems to make no difference what the action or controller is. Changing browser from Chrome to Firefox didn't help.

```
<script>
$('.zzz').click(function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/XXX/yyy',
        data: { test: "hello" },
        type: "post",
        success: function () { alert("success"); },
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class XXXController : AsyncController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YYY()
    {
        return null;     // ====== NEVER REACHES HERE
    }
}
```

Headers

```
Request URL:http://localhost:47038/xxx/yyy
Request Method:POST
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Remote Address:[::1]:47038
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
=================
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:154
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 21 Nov 2017 16:02:23 GMT
Location:http://localhost:47038/xxx/yyy/
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcdmF1bHRccHJpbnRlcnBpeG12Y3VpXFByaW50ZXJQaXhNdmNVSVxYWFhcWVlZ?=

Request Headers
================
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:10
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=rargvavdg0reeuhqvqkznsaj; MachineToken=a2fec363-6318-4ec3-8d2c-0eee116fc778; __RequestVerificationToken=80gj5joNWUpBjgjOsxkV0SkDwhrX3fNbzYTZrTaUGpJXlIEY7nyguehSDpz525JKyNfjlI5Two-poQs1dC2jw0kWnpvnK74iz4X3KV5MtSI1
Host:localhost:47038
Origin:http://localhost:47038
Referer:http://localhost:47038/xxx/Index/?product=puzzle
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Form Data
==========
test:hello
```

GET requests are working fine, it is just POSTs which are being redirected.

Why is 301 "Moved Permanently" being returned, instead of the Action method being executed?

Comment: Check your request pipeline. You might have some action/result filters which is returning that response

Comment: There is code to do it in a RequireSSL attribute, but as far as i can tell that is never being called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to put a forward-slash on the end of the postback URL:

```
url: '/XXX/yyy'   ==> 301 Moved Permanently
url: '/XXX/yyy/'  ==> 200 OK
```

Very embarassing waste of a day's work.